# TinyMCE editor does not display content of Text Area in Mozila firefox

Tags: asp.net, firefox, tinymce-4

I have one module in which I displayed TinyMCE editor in a modal popup.

On page load, I bind HTML content as text of text area, and after that, I give that text area control as a selector of tinymce editor.

**HTML of text area which is present in the modal popup:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEditorContent" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" CssClass="editor-content" TextMode="MultiLine" />
```

I have one function which is executed when there is an active tinymce editor on page and user clicks on a button which is used to open the modal popup in which another tinymce editor is present, which displayed confirmation message box that whether to save the changes or not.

if user clicks yes then i removed the active editor on page using code

```
tinymce.remove();
```

But the content of text area is not displayed in TinyMCE editor.

When i opened the modal popup it displayed as below.
[image]

I also checked by inspect element in mozilla, it shows me that there is no content in  of tinymce.

[image]

**Javascript fired on opening the modal popup:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
         tinymce.remove();
         tinymce.init({
            selector: '.editor-content',
            menubar: false,
            branding: false,
            height: 350,
            code_dialog_height: 200,                
            plugins: ['advlist autolink lists charmap print preview anchor textcolor code', 'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen', 'insertdatetime table contextmenu paste code help wordcount'],
            toolbar: 'insert | undo redo |  formatselect | bold italic backcolor  | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | table | code ',
        });
});
```

Can anybody tell me what I am missing?

**Note: This issue is not reproduced in the Google Chrome and only in Mozilla Firefox.**

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @Juggernaut I solved this issue by giving timeout of 500 milliseconds for initializing the tinymce. Now it works fine in Mozilla.